# HDMI PORT not working

Tags: windows, hdmi

I have a ASUS K53SV laptop. I was using the HDMI port for about a year with my Samsung TV, and an external monitor. One day it lost signal and now my laptop no longer displays picture or sound through the HDMI port.

But here is the really strange part, it still recognizes my Samsung TV as an external monitor, but only when the TV is turned off. When i turn of the TV my screen flickers and my computer goes into multiple display mode. Also sometimes when I uninstall my generic PnP driver and then restart my computer while connected to the TV, I can get picture to show up but at some strange resolution.

My graphics card is a GT540m, with a secondary Intel HD 3000. Im pretty sure the HD3000 is what controls the HDMI port. I have already tried updating my drivers for

Comment: Do you have any other HDMI-out devices to test with the TV?

Comment: Yes my xbox works, my dvd player works, other laptops work.

Comment: Have you tried to connect the laptop to another HDMI port on the TV and, have you tried connecting the laptop to any other HDMI display?